# Is it mandatory to install a PKCS12/PFX cert in keystore before using it?

Tags: c#, windows, ssl, x509, pfx

I am facing an issue while using client certificate in a http client application in C#. The client certificate is delivered by server at runtime as X509Certificate. I have private key as well. So I generate PKCS12/PFX object (X509Certificate2). Now when I run this application in a multithreaded environment, where in each thread creates a new SSL connection using the different client certificates received from server, randomly some of the SSL handshake fails and some passes. Network trace shows SSL handshake fails right after client sends client certificate.

Note that I have not stored X509Certificate2 in a store. If I don't use client certificate, everything works fine (server sends 401 as it needs client cert, but SSL handshake never fails).

Is it because I am not installing client certificate X509Certificate2 object in store? Is it mandatory to install PKCS12 certs in store?

Here is method for SSL handshake:

```
        public void SslHandshake(ConnectionParams connectionParams)
        {
            TcpClient mClient = new TcpClient(connectionParams.HostFqdn, connectionParams.Port);
            SslStream mSslStream = new SslStream(mClient.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);
            try
            {
                if (connectionParams.ClientCertificate != null)
                {
                    mSslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(connectionParams.HostFqdn, new X509Certificate2Collection(connectionParams.ClientCertificate), SslProtocols.Tls12, false);
                }
                else
                {
                    mSslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(connectionParams.HostFqdn);
                }
            }
            catch (AuthenticationException e)
            {
                sLog.Error("Exception establishing SSL connection: " + e.Message);
                if (e.InnerException != null)
                {
                    sLog.Error("Inner exception establishing SSL connection: " + e.InnerException.Message);
                }
                mSslStream.Close();
                mClient.Close();
                throw new ApiException("SSL handshake failed - closing the connection.");
            }
        }
```

**=======EDIT=======**

This is the method to generate DotNet X509Certificate2 object using bouncycastle X509Certficate and private key.

```
public System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 CreatePkcs12(X509Certificate bcCert, AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey)
        {
            var x509Certificate = DotNetUtilities.ToX509Certificate(bcCert);
            var certBytes = x509Certificate.Export(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType.Pkcs12, IosHelper.DEVICE_CERT_PFX_PASSWORD);
            var certificate = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(certBytes, IosHelper.DEVICE_CERT_PFX_PASSWORD, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
            if(privateKey != null)
            {
                var rsaParams = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters(privateKey as RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters);
                var cspParams = new CspParameters();
                cspParams.KeyContainerName = "KeyContainer";
                var rsaPrivate = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
                rsaPrivate.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
                certificate.PrivateKey = rsaPrivate;
            }
            return certificate;
        }
```

Comment: It is recommended that way, as you can allow Windows to control the private key ACL and other security settings. If you don't you can of course load certificates directly from .pfx files, but then you need to protect the file and its private key yourself.

Comment: Hi @LexLi thanks for replying. If these certificates and private keys are not sensitive. Just some test data. It's fine to not install them in store, right?

Comment: Right, technically speaking you can load from .pfx file directly, and `X509Certificate2` has a few constructors for that.

Comment: In my case it's not a PFX file. So I am wondering if it has to do something with the way I am generating the PFX object. I just updated my question with code to generate PKCS12. Does it look ok? 

My issue is, everything works fine until 3 threads. If I increase further, SSL handshake starts failing with SSL Fatal Alert "Bad Certificate". Even though client certificate looks proper in network trace.

Comment: Do you have access to the server side? Maybe it simply does not trust the certificate (as it was generated on the fly). Verify if you install root/intermediate certificates properly on the server side. Mutual SSL authentication has its special settings, which is too broad to discuss in a comment, but Google should teach on those.

Comment: "he client certificate is delivered by server at runtime..." That doesn't make sense to me. The client certificate has to have your public key in it.

Comment: james, it's delivered as a http payload. Yes, it has public key. lex, the CA and intermediate certs are installed on server. Is there any otger parameter in client cert exchange that can cause the bad cert error?